# Why are Google authentication consent screen buttons disabled on an Android 2.3 phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, authorization

I want to use an old Galaxy Ace which runs Android 2.3 as a camera. I installed the Alfred camera app on it which requires Google login in order to connect the camera and the viewer device securely.

I can log in successfully with the Alfred app to Google, but then there is a consent screen to allow the app to access my account data and both buttons are disabled like here on this picture taken from the net.

[image]

Why is it that loggging in works, but I cannot proceed from the consent screen? How can this be fixed?

Comment: This login screen is actually a web page shown. I would assume that the used web browser component is too old. If this page is shown within an app then it uses the "Android System WebView" which is most likely a bit out-of-date on that device. May be it is that old that some of the included JavaScript fails and therefore the buttons remain disabled. Try to update the "Android System WebView" app.

Comment: @Robert you may be right, I searched for it and found this: "In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views” "  https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.htm it looks like the version of Alfred I can install which supports android 2.3 uses a webview for login which is restricted by google, so it's may be the end of the line, because I can't install a newer Alfred, they've dropped 2.3 support for quite a while